# How to send mails from Magento?

Tags: email, magento, localhost, mamp

I have installed Magento 1.7 on my mac. What should I do to send emails about orders from localhost. I'm developing store localy and just want to check how it works.

Comment: enable SMTP, go to Magento admin system configuration and select emails for orders,invoices,etc..

Answer (score 0):

Use the tool give on this link [Test mail tool](http://www.toolheap.com/test-mail-server-tool/)

For sending the emails you need SMTP server which listens to port number 25.By default there is no SMTP server with wamp. So you  need to use some SMTP tool to check email sending feature in local environment.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @ChristianStewart I have modified my answer.

Comment: I think that tool is only for win, but as I said I have mac :/

Comment: @LaKaede Try this mocksmtpapp.com/ .I have not tested this but you have Mac OS you can try this and check. Or google for some SMTP tool fro localhost for Mac OS